# Reading a file in C and copying the contents to an array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I've been learning C for a few weeks and I've been stuck a couple of days with this matter.

I'm trying to read a file that has some information about movies and copy it to an array of structures.

```
main(){

struct movies{

    char name[30];
    char director[30];
    char yearOfRelease[30];
    char budget[30];
    char image[30];
    char genre[30];
};

struct movies mvArray[100];

struct movies data;

FILE *readingText;
readingText = fopen("movies.txt", "r");
char c[150];
int lines = 0;

do{

    fgets(c, 150, readingText);

    if(lines % 6 == 0)
    {
        strcpy(data.name, c);


    }

    if(lines % 6 == 1)
    {
        strcpy(data.director, c);
    }



    if(lines % 6 == 3)
    {
        strcpy(data.budget, c);
    }
    if(lines % 6 == 4)
    {
        strcpy(data.image, c);
    }
    if(lines % 6 == 5)
    {
        strcpy(data.genre, c);
    }

    mvArray[lines] = data;

    lines++;
}

while((fgets(c, 150, readingText) != NULL));

fclose(readingText);

}
```

The if statements seem to work well and catch the exact line that I want. If I do a printf inside the if statement, it catches the line.

But for some reason I'm not able to save the data properly inside the array of structures.

Outside of the do while loop, if I do a

```
printf("%s", mvArray[1].name);
```

it will print the line out, so it saved that line into the correct place in the array of structures. But it only does that with the first 2 variables of the array of structures, only with name and director, so I must be missing something.

Thanks a lot and kind regards.

EDIT:

This is the text file that I'm reading.

```
Name: SomeMovie
Director: Someone
Release year: 1995
budget: 10000
Image: fasdf.jpg
Genre: Horror
Name: SomeMovie
Director: Someone
Release year: 1995
budget: 10000
Image: fasdf.jpg
Genre: Horror
```

The if statements seem to catch the information well. If I do a printf("%s", c); inside each of the if statment, it will print out the exact line that I want. But I'm not able to store it inside the array of structures.

Comment: What if `lines % 6 == 2`? Is it deliberate that you're skipping it? The way I see it you wanted to set `yearOfRelease` there, but because it's missing, it won't be set and you will get rubbish when trying to print it (undefined behavior, to be precise).

Comment: Comment edited with the txt file.

Comment: You also need to extract the information from your line, right now the whole line `"Name: SomeMovie"` will be copied into the struct but you probably want just `"SomeMovie"` to be copied.

Comment: I wonder why you are calling a struct representing one movie "movies". Do we have types named `ints` and `chars` and `doubles` in C? Nope, we have `int` and `char` and `double`. Why `movies`? OTOH an array of such structs can be reasonably called `movies`: `struct movie movies[100];`, because it contains several movies, and we already know it's an array because of the `[...]`, no need to repeat this all over the place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

  struct movie {
    char name[30];
    char director[30];
    char yearOfRelease[30];
    char budget[30];
    char image[30];
    char genre[30];
  };

  struct movie mvArray[100];    
  struct movie data;

  FILE *readingText;
  readingText = fopen("movies.txt", "r");

  if (readingText == NULL)
  {
    printf("Can't open file\n");
    return 1;
  }

  char c[150];
  int lines = 0;

  while ((fgets(c, 150, readingText) != NULL))
  {
    fgets(c, 150, readingText);

    switch (lines % 6)
    {
    case 0:
      strcpy(data.name, c);
      break;

    case 1:
      strcpy(data.director, c);
      break;

    case 2:
      //... to be done...
      // probably strcpy(data.yearOfRelease, c);
      break;

    case 3:
      strcpy(data.budget, c);
      break;

    case 4:
      strcpy(data.image, c);
      break;

    case 5:
      strcpy(data.genre, c);
      break;
  }

    mvArray[lines] = data;
    lines++;
  }

  fclose(readingText);
}
```

Modifications:

1. `fgets` is called only once per loop at the beginning
2. uses the less cumbersome `switch/case` instead of multiple `if`s
3. case 2 needs to be treated
4. handle the case where the file could not be opened
5. `struct movies` renamed to `struct movie` (one struct contains one and only one movie).

There is still room for further improvement.

For example you could copy directly into `mvArray` like this `strcpy(mvArray[lines].genre, c);` and drop the `data` variable alltogether.

Also `lines` should be `line`.